# Page not showing after add a function on child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I am using Genesis framework and modern-studio-pro as a child theme. I have just copy this code

```
function genesis_standard_loop() {

//* Use old loop hook structure if not supporting HTML5
if ( ! genesis_html5() ) {
    genesis_legacy_loop();
    return;
}

if ( have_posts() ) :

    do_action( 'genesis_before_while' );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        do_action( 'genesis_before_entry' );

        printf( '<article %s>', genesis_attr( 'entry' ) );

            do_action( 'genesis_entry_header' );

            do_action( 'genesis_before_entry_content' );

            printf( '<div %s>', genesis_attr( 'entry-content' ) );
            do_action( 'genesis_entry_content' );
            echo '</div>';

            do_action( 'genesis_after_entry_content' );

            do_action( 'genesis_entry_footer' );

        echo '</article>';

        do_action( 'genesis_after_entry' );

    endwhile; //* end of one post
    do_action( 'genesis_after_endwhile' );

else : //* if no posts exist
    do_action( 'genesis_loop_else' );
endif; //* end loop

}
```

from Genesis to child theme `functions.php`. After that my site is showing

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare genesis_standard_loop() (previously declared in /home/u282646374/public_html/wp-content/themes/modern-studio-pro/functions.php:198) in /home/u282646374/public_html/wp-content/themes/genesis/lib/structure/loops.php on line 115

I have delete that code from child theme but site not showing. Please tell me how can i regain my site? This is the link of my page http://andrewspalding.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are redeclaring the function `genesis_standard_loop()` inside `functions.php` of your child theme while on the main genesis theme this function is inside `lib/structure/loops.php` child themes will overwrite the parent theme functions if they are inside the same file that they are in the parent theme, if you want to modify a function from the parent theme you might contemplate the idea of looking for `filters` or `actions`.

If you MUST redeclare the function try recreating the same file structure, but remember to add all of the other functions inside that particular file.